# Removing mouse controls from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, processing, mouse, p5.js

I have a large piece of code that draws feather-looking designs controlled by the mouse. This is using mouse pressed and mouseX, mouseY.

I would like the code to run and draw the feathers without the mouse being involved (ie. opening the canvas and having feathers automatically draw on the screen).

The full code is below:

```js
var points = [];
var painting = false;
var strokeNumber = 0;

var scl = 6;
var cols, rows;
var inc = 0.1;
var zOff = 0;
var particles = [];
var flowField = [];
var saturation = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  // createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  pixelDensity(5);
  background(0);
  
  cols = floor(width / scl);
  rows = floor(height / scl);
  
  flowField = Array(cols * rows);
  saturation = Array(width * height).fill(0);
  greateForceField();
  
}

function mousePressed() {
  painting = true;
  strokeNumber++;
}

function mouseReleased() {
  painting = false;
}

function updateForceField(){
  var v = createVector(mouseX, mouseY);
  var vPrev = createVector(pmouseX, pmouseY);
  v.sub(vPrev);
  v.setMag(1);
  var i = floor(mouseX / scl);
  var j = floor(mouseY / scl);
  var index =  i * rows + j;
  flowField[index] = v;
}

function showForceField(){
  for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      var index = i * rows + j;
      var v = flowField[index];
      stroke(0,50);
      strokeWeight(1);
      push();      
      translate(i * scl, j * scl);
      rotate(v.heading());
      line(0,0,scl,0);
      pop();
    }    
  }
}

function greateForceField(){
  var xOff = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    var yOff = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      yOff += inc; 
      var angle = noise(xOff, yOff, zOff) * TWO_PI;
      var v = p5.Vector.fromAngle(angle);
      v.setMag(.1);
      var index = i * rows + j;
      flowField[index] = v;
    }
    xOff += inc;
  }
  // zOff += inc * 0.1;
}

function draw() {
  // background(255);
  // showForceField();
  
  if(painting){
    updateForceField();

    var idx = mouseY * width + mouseX;
    if(saturation[idx] < 10){
      var r = 1+sqrt(sq(mouseX-pmouseX)+sq(mouseY-pmouseY));
      for(var a = 0; a < 100; a++){
        var particle = new Particle(mouseX+random()*r*cos(random(TWO_PI)), mouseY+random()*r*sin(random(TWO_PI)));
        particles.push(particle);
      }
      saturation[idx] ++;
    }
  }
  
  particles.filter(particle => particle.spread > 0).map(particle => {
    particle.update();
    particle.show();
    // particle.edges();
    particle.follow();
  })
  
  particles.map((particle, idx) => {
    if(particle.spread <= 0){
      particles.splice(idx,1);
    }
  });
  
}

function Particle(x,y){  
  this.pos = createVector(x,y);
  // this.color = color(245, 225, 50);
  // this.color = color(145, 225, 192);
  this.color = color(255);
  this.spread = 127;
  this.spreadInc = this.spread/100;
  
  this.prevPos = this.pos.copy();
  this.vel = p5.Vector.random2D();
  this.acc = createVector(0,0);
  this.maxSpeed = 2;
  
  this.update = function(){
    this.spread -= this.spreadInc;
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.vel.limit(this.maxSpeed);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.mult(0);
  }
  
  this.applyForce = function(force){
    this.acc.add(force);
  }
  
  this.follow = function(){
    var i = floor(this.pos.x / scl);
    var j = floor(this.pos.y / scl);
    var index =  i * rows + j;
    var force = flowField[index];
    this.applyForce(force);    
  }
  
  this.show = function(){
    stroke(red(this.color),green(this.color),blue(this.color),this.spread);
    strokeWeight(.3*this.spread/127);
    // point(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    line(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.prevPos.x, this.prevPos.y);
    this.updatePrev();
  }
  
  this.updatePrev = function(){
    this.prevPos = this.pos.copy();
  }
  
  this.edges = function(){
    if(this.pos.x > width) {
      this.pos.x = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.x < 0){
      this.pos.x = width;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.y > height){
      this.pos.y = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.y < 0) {
      this.pos.y = height;
      this.updatePrev();
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: So where is the mouse event code?

Comment: @epascarello This is [p5.js](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed)

Comment: in `draw()` change mouseX and mouseY to variables you control and come up with a convincing algorithm to produce the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 4 variables `current_x`, `current_y`, `prev_x` and `prev_y` instead of `mosueX`, `mouseY`, `pmouseX` and `pmouseY`.

```js
var current_x=0, current_y=0, prev_x=0, prev_y=0;

function updateForceField(){
    var v = createVector(current_x, current_y);
    var vPrev = createVector(prev_x, prev_y);
    v.sub(vPrev);
    v.setMag(1);
    var i = floor(current_x / scl);
    var j = floor(current_y / scl);
    var index =  i * rows + j;
    flowField[index] = v;
}
```

Instead of the state `painting` use a time interval. The time between 2 frames can be get from the built-in variable [`deltaTime`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/deltaTime) (in milliseconds). Set the x and y positions by random values. e.g.:

```js
var interval = 200; // 200 milliseconds
var sum_time = 0;

function draw() {

    sum_time += deltaTime;
    if(sum_time > interval){
        sum_time = 0;

        current_x = Math.floor(random(width));
        current_y = Math.floor(random(height));
        updateForceField();
        prev_x = current_x;
        prev_y = current_y; 

        var idx = current_y * width + current_x;
        if(saturation[idx] < 10){
            var r = 1+sqrt(sq(current_x-prev_x)+sq(current_y-prev_y));
            for(var a = 0; a < 100; a++){
                var particle = new Particle(current_x+random()*r*cos(random(TWO_PI)), current_y+random()*r*sin(random(TWO_PI)));
                particles.push(particle);
            }
            saturation[idx] ++;
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

See the example:

```js
var points = [];
var painting = false;
var strokeNumber = 0;

var scl = 6;
var cols, rows;
var inc = 0.1;
var zOff = 0;
var particles = [];
var flowField = [];
var saturation = [];

function setup() {
  //createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  createCanvas(500, 200);

  pixelDensity(5);
  background(0);

  cols = floor(width / scl);
  rows = floor(height / scl);

  flowField = Array(cols * rows);
  saturation = Array(width * height).fill(0);
  greateForceField();

}

function mousePressed() {
  painting = true;
  strokeNumber++;
}

function mouseReleased() {
  painting = false;
}

var current_x=0, current_y=0, prev_x=0, prev_y=0;

function updateForceField(){
    var v = createVector(current_x, current_y);
    var vPrev = createVector(prev_x, prev_y);
    v.sub(vPrev);
    v.setMag(1);
    var i = floor(current_x / scl);
    var j = floor(current_y / scl);
    var index =  i * rows + j;
    flowField[index] = v;
}

function showForceField(){
  for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      var index = i * rows + j;
      var v = flowField[index];
      stroke(0,50);
      strokeWeight(1);
      push();      
      translate(i * scl, j * scl);
      rotate(v.heading());
      line(0,0,scl,0);
      pop();
    }    
  }
}

function greateForceField(){
  var xOff = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    var yOff = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < rows; j++){
      yOff += inc; 
      var angle = noise(xOff, yOff, zOff) * TWO_PI;
      var v = p5.Vector.fromAngle(angle);
      v.setMag(.1);
      var index = i * rows + j;
      flowField[index] = v;
    }
    xOff += inc;
  }
  // zOff += inc * 0.1;
}

var interval = 200; // 200 milliseconds
var sum_time = 0;

function draw() {
    // background(255);
    // showForceField();

    sum_time += deltaTime;
    if(sum_time > interval){
        sum_time = 0;

        current_x = Math.floor(random(width));
        current_y = Math.floor(random(height));
        updateForceField();
        prev_x = current_x;
        prev_y = current_y; 

        var idx = current_y * width + current_x;
        if(saturation[idx] < 10){
            var r = 1+sqrt(sq(current_x-prev_x)+sq(current_y-prev_y));
            for(var a = 0; a < 100; a++){
                var particle = new Particle(current_x+random()*r*cos(random(TWO_PI)), current_y+random()*r*sin(random(TWO_PI)));
                particles.push(particle);
            }
            saturation[idx] ++;
        }
    }

    particles.filter(particle => particle.spread > 0).map(particle => {
        particle.update();
        particle.show();
        // particle.edges();
        particle.follow();
    })

    particles.map((particle, idx) => {
        if(particle.spread <= 0){
            particles.splice(idx,1);
        }
    });
}

function Particle(x,y){  
  this.pos = createVector(x,y);
  // this.color = color(245, 225, 50);
  // this.color = color(145, 225, 192);
  this.color = color(255);
  this.spread = 127;
  this.spreadInc = this.spread/100;

  this.prevPos = this.pos.copy();
  this.vel = p5.Vector.random2D();
  this.acc = createVector(0,0);
  this.maxSpeed = 2;

  this.update = function(){
    this.spread -= this.spreadInc;
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.vel.limit(this.maxSpeed);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.mult(0);
  }

  this.applyForce = function(force){
    this.acc.add(force);
  }

  this.follow = function(){
    var i = floor(this.pos.x / scl);
    var j = floor(this.pos.y / scl);
    var index =  i * rows + j;
    var force = flowField[index];
    this.applyForce(force);    
  }

  this.show = function(){
    stroke(red(this.color),green(this.color),blue(this.color),this.spread);
    strokeWeight(.3*this.spread/127);
    // point(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
    line(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.prevPos.x, this.prevPos.y);
    this.updatePrev();
  }

  this.updatePrev = function(){
    this.prevPos = this.pos.copy();
  }

  this.edges = function(){
    if(this.pos.x > width) {
      this.pos.x = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.x < 0){
      this.pos.x = width;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.y > height){
      this.pos.y = 0;
      this.updatePrev();
    }
    if(this.pos.y < 0) {
      this.pos.y = height;
      this.updatePrev();
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sbez It seems that `deltaTime` is not defined in this case. Use `sum_time += 20;` instead of `sum_time += deltaTime;`